# Does DACPAC creation is doing any blocking on database / server level?

Tags: sql-server-2019, visual-studio, data-tier-application

I have to create DACPAC from production database. I would like to do this via Visual Studio 2022 (SQL Server Object Explorer and "Extract - Data-tier application"). Is it possibility to block any processes / queries or utilize more CPU / memory doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possibility to block any processes / queries or utilize more CPU / memory doing it ?

Nothing is free. Of course it'll utilize some hardware resources of the SQL Server machine. I believe this process likely queries system objects (the `sys` schema) of the database. Regardless, any query is going to use some level of resources.

That being said, generally, querying the basic system objects (`sys.tables`, `sys.views`, `sys.objects`, etc) uses very minimal amount of resources. They are simplistic queries. Most things shouldn't get blocked when reading from them, as far as I know. But I'm sure there are very specific situations that it's a possibility.

At the end of the day, it'll always depend on your system, how well it's provisioned, how busy it already is, and the type of new queries being introduced, to determine if it can tolerate them, even for generating a DACPAC. The best way to find out, is to actually test doing it. But I would say 9/10 times this process is relatively safe to run.